# How to implement multiple fragment in one Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement 10 fragments in single activity each fragment have a single button and occupy whole screen, when button is pressed fragment is change to another fragment to do this i make interface in `Fragment1` called `OnFragmentChangeListener` which have `changefragment()` method i implement `OnFragmentChangeListener` interface in main activity and define `changeFragment()`.

My program sucessfully transaction from fragment 1 to fragment 2 but i can't able to implement this for 10 fragment.

Comment: Show us the code. :)

Comment: Use a framelayout and fragment transaction to replace fragments